# App Store and Ad Hoc production certificate is enough for Push Notification Distribution?

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am going to upload my first iOS App.I am Integrating Firebase Push Notification in my iOS App. Which certificate i need for Distribution?   App Store and Ad Hoc production certificate is only enough for App distribution? or I need  both App Store and Ad Hoc ,Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) or only Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)?

hope you understand my problem.Thanks In advance[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only certificate you require for distribution:

[image]